# Huffman vs RLE in Hexadecimal

Tags: compression, huffman-code, run-length-encoding

I'm trying to compress a file with hexadecimal characters, but i don't know if it would be efficient to use the Huffman Codification, because the RLE depends on the file and the characters, and this never is the same if I change file to compress.

Should I use Huffman? If it is inefficient, why is it? Is there any known algorythm which I could use to compress it better, being possible to me to write it as code in any language?

Comment: Is it always just hexadecimal characters? If so, converting that file to base 256 would make it half as big guaranteed, and entirely "for free" (no headers, no serious processing cost, not conditional on the contents except that it's hexadecimal)

Comment: What is "a file with hexadecimal characters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If RLE works, Huffman will work all the better. There's a proof that if your file is large enough, Huffman will converge to the maximum possible entropy, thus maximizing compression.

Comment: And is it possible that the Huffman encoding could expand the file? So in this way, RLE would expand more the file than Huffman?

Comment: RLE can provide better compression in certain circumstances. i.e. If there are very long runs of the same characters.

Comment: Um, no, not unless your Huffman "symbols" are really long strings of bytes, which would require impossibly long files to get a benefit.  RLE can take advantage of redundancy that Huffman coding on byte symbols cannot.

Comment: @MarkAdler: I generally agree, but he's not specifying how his Huffman dictionary is built. This is up to implementation, so I chose to imagine an encoder that was *clever* in this particular case.
Take for example a sliding window compression algorithm: If your window is sized to span one but not too many constant regions, then adaptive huffman will quickly reduce whichever symbol length is used to be represented by a single bit; now, this will only lead to a compression ratio of up to 16, but usually you can do that iteratively :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should convert every two hexadecimal characters to one byte.  That will get you a factor of two right off the bat.

Second, you can apply both RLE (or better LZ77 matching strings which is a generalization of RLE) and Huffman depending on what redundancy there is in the resulting bytes, if any.  Existing compression methods like zlib will do this for you, applying both.

Comment: exactly! Upvoting a competing answer for pure quality :)